# Junit: Setting up new instance of object for every test, something strange happens when run multiple tests at once

Tags: java, junit5

I have been trying to write JUnit tests to test a program but something seems to be wrong and I can't figure out what. The program works as intended, but the unittests behaves strangely when run together.

I want to create a new instance of the ParkingLotManager object for every test, and have tried to instansiate a new object in every test-method, as well as in the @BeforeEach. Still, when running the tests one by one, it all works fine, but when run together it all goes to hell.

Previously I couldn't get the @BeforeEach method to run, but that seems to have been a Maven compatibility issue. It seems to work now with printing stuff out at least.

I have been struggeling with this all day, and rewriting stuff a million times, so sorry if it's a bit messy.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Other feedback on the code is also appreciated.

ParkingLotManager class that is to be tested:

```
package com.mycompany.graduatecase;

import java.util.*;
import com.mycompany.graduatecase.ParkingSpot;
import static com.mycompany.graduatecase.SpaceShipParking.calculateDuration;
import static com.mycompany.graduatecase.SpaceShipParking.calculatePrice;
import static com.mycompany.graduatecase.SpaceShipParking.input;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


public class ParkingLotManager {

    private static ArrayList<ParkingSpot> parkingLot = new ArrayList<ParkingSpot>(); 
    private static ParkingRecords parkingRecords = new ParkingRecords();

    
    public ParkingLotManager(int levels, int parkingsPerLevel) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                parkingLot.add(new ParkingSpot(i+1, j+1));
            }

        }
    }
    
    public void displayLot(){
        for (int i = 0; i < parkingLot.size();i++) 
          {
              System.out.println("Våning: " + parkingLot.get(i).level + " Number: " + parkingLot.get(i).number + " Is available: " + parkingLot.get(i).isAvailable);        
          }   
    }
    
    public ParkingSpot getParkingSpot(int level, int number){
        for (int i = 0; i < parkingLot.size();i++)
            if (parkingLot.get(i).level == level)
                if(parkingLot.get(i).number == number){
                    return parkingLot.get(i); 
                }
        return null; 
    }
    
    public ParkingSpot getAvailableParkingSpot(){
        for (int i = 0; i < parkingLot.size();i++){
            if (parkingLot.get(i).isAvailable){
                return parkingLot.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }
    

    
        /*
    * Registers a designated parking spot on first available parking spot, 
    * starting on level 1, spot 1. 
    */
    public void registerParking(String regNo){
        if (getAvailableParkingSpot() == null){
            System.out.println("No available parkings right now, please come back later. ");
        }else{
        ParkingSpot parkingSpot = getAvailableParkingSpot();
        System.out.println("\nPlease park on assigned parkingspot.");
        System.out.println("Level: " + parkingSpot.level + " Number: " + parkingSpot.number);
        parkingSpot.spotTaken();
        
        parkingRecords.addRecord(regNo, parkingSpot);

        }
    }
    
    /*
    * Returns -1 when no found parking for regNo, otherwise returns duration for parking.
    */
    public int registerPickup(String regNo){
        ParkRecord parkingRecord = parkingRecords.findLatestParkingOnRegNo(regNo);
        int durationParked = 0;
        if ( parkingRecord == null){
            System.out.println("Vi hittade inte din parkering. Försök igen.");
        }else{
        parkingRecord.setTo(LocalDateTime.now());    
        ParkingSpot spot = parkingRecord.getParkingSpot();
        getParkingSpot(spot.level, spot.number).spotFreed();
        durationParked = calculateDuration(parkingRecord.getFrom(), parkingRecord.getTo());
        return durationParked; 
        }
        return -1; 
    }   
    

    
    
    
}
```

And here's the test class:

```
package com.mycompany.graduatecase;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

public class ParkingLotManagerTest {
    
    private ParkingLotManager parkingLot; 
    
    public ParkingLotManagerTest() {
    }
    
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
        
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        parkingLot = new ParkingLotManager(3, 15);
    }
    
    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of getParkingSpot method, of class ParkingLotManager.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetParkingSpot() {
        System.out.println("getParkingSpot");
        int level = 1;
        int number = 1;        

        ParkingSpot expectedObject = new ParkingSpot(level, number);
        ParkingSpot actualObject = parkingLot.getParkingSpot(level, number);
//        assertThat(actualObject)
//            .usingRecursiveComparison()
//            .isEqualTo(expectedObject);
        assertEquals(expectedObject.level, actualObject.level);
        assertEquals(expectedObject.number, actualObject.number);
    }

    
    
    @Test
    public void testGetAvailableParkingSpot() {
        System.out.println("getAvailableParkingSpot returns right object");
        int level = 1;
        int number = 1;
        //ParkingLotManager parkingLot = new ParkingLotManager(3, 15);
        ParkingSpot expectedObject = new ParkingSpot(level, number);
        ParkingSpot actualObject = parkingLot.getAvailableParkingSpot();
        assertThat(actualObject)
            .usingRecursiveComparison()
            .isEqualTo(expectedObject);  
    }
   

    @Test
    public void testGetAvailableParkingSpot2() {
        
        System.out.println("getAvailableParkingSpot returns right object after registering 3 parkings");        
        int level = 1;
        int number = 4;
        //ParkingLotManager parkingLot = new ParkingLotManager(3, 15);
        ParkingSpot expectedObject = new ParkingSpot(level, number);
       
        parkingLot.registerParking("123"); 
        parkingLot.registerParking("234"); 
        parkingLot.registerParking("456");
        
        ParkingSpot actualObject = parkingLot.getAvailableParkingSpot(); 
        
        assertThat(actualObject)
            .usingRecursiveComparison()
            .isEqualTo(expectedObject); 
           
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAvailableParkingSpot3() {
        
        System.out.println("getAvailableParkingSpot returns right object after registering 3 parkings and removing 1");        
        int level = 1;
        int number = 2;
        //ParkingLotManager parkingLot = new ParkingLotManager(3, 15);
        ParkingSpot expectedObject = new ParkingSpot(level, number);
        
        parkingLot.registerParking("123"); 
        parkingLot.registerParking("234"); 
        parkingLot.registerParking("456");
        
        
        parkingLot.registerPickup("234");
        
        ParkingSpot actualObject = parkingLot.getAvailableParkingSpot(); 
        
        assertThat(actualObject)
            .usingRecursiveComparison()
            .isEqualTo(expectedObject); 
           
    }




}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What exactly do you mean by "something strange happens" and "all goes to hell"? Do tests fail (which ones, and how?), do you see exceptions (which ones, where)? What is the expected and actual behavior? What change exactly made it work?

Comment: Quick guess: your code under test, `ParkingLotManager`, uses `static` variables. These are not per-object, but shared among all instances of the class. Remove `static`. If tests run concurrently, they may mess with each others variables.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit vague. It seemed like the tests weren't starting from empty as user12669945 said. I knew it was something simple, removing the static and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Robert's quick guess. I think he hit the nail on the head.

If your tests are running concurrently, they will have different ParkingLotManager objects that all share the same underlying data, which is clearly going to be a big concurrency problem. Even if they run serially, the data from the last test will remain so the future tests will end up NOT starting from "Empty".

So, if you know the tests run in order (and not all simultaneously), you can test this theory by adding a call in @AfterEach to a new function parkingLot.reset();

Implement the .reset() function in ParkingLotManager where .reset() clears the underlying (static) lists. That way, each time the previous test completes, the next one has a "fresh" list to work with. This will then make it "appear" as if you are getting a clean ParkingLotManager, instead of a new object with a handle to an old List.

```
private static ArrayList<ParkingSpot> parkingLot = new ArrayList<ParkingSpot>(); 
private static ParkingRecords parkingRecords = new ParkingRecords();
```

I would do what Robert said and try to take the static's out so it behaves likely more as you expected.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the problem, removed the static and now i works. You saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
private ParkingLotManager parkingLot;

...

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        parkingLot = new ParkingLotManager(3, 15);
    }
```

and add local variable
`ParkingLotManager parkingLot = new ParkingLotManager(3, 15);`
on beginning of each test or equivalent of a constructor function (e.g `getParkingLotManager3_15()`) to not duplicate the code.

You should not have property that belong to test class, when you run tests parallel

Comment: This won't help  because of static variables in class under test.  All data is still shared because of those static variables.